# ActiveRecord fetching records from has_many and related relationship through scopes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: `Customer` and `Order`. Sometimes it happens that two Customers are actually the same customer, which is indicated by one of them having a `master_id` which points to another Customer record. When fetching Orders for a customer, I'd also like to fetch Orders from slave Customers (i.e. the ones that claim the Customer I'm querying from is their master Customer record).

So:

```
Customer1: id: 1, master_id: nil, orders: [Order1, Order2]

Customer2: id: 2, master_id: 1, orders: [Order3]
```

query `Customer1.all_orders` should return all 3 `Order` objects

I know how to do this through a method - pluck ids of slave Customers, add the original customer's id to the array and then look for Orders whose customer_id is in this array:

```
has_many :slave_records, class_name: 'Customer', foreign_key: 'master_id'

def all_orders
  order_ids = slave_records.map(&:id).push(id)
  Order.where(customer_id: order_ids)
end
```

But is there a way to do this using scopes and relations? It's Rails 4 (I know that Rails 5 was supposed to have an OR thing in its version of ActiveRecord).

Comment: It would be much helpful if you could paste some part of the code that you have implemented so far

Comment: @usmanali I've added the method that I have implemented already - I want to implement this using scopes and relations

Comment: Can you try this `scope: :all_orders -> { [orders, slave_records.map(&:orders)].flatten }`?

Comment: @31piy This doesn't work, since scope - like the one you mentioned - works on relations, not on single objects, so customer_1.all_orders in this case returns an error `undefined method `all_orders' for #<Customer:...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding scope in Order model will get you closer to what you want.

```
class Order
  scope :for_master, -> (master) { where("customer_id = #{master.id} OR customer_id IN (?)", master.slave_records.select(:id)) }
end
```

So for any master customer, call the scope and you will get orders for children too.

```
Order.for_master(customer)
```

You will not be able to call `customer.all_orders`. But, you will be able to get all results in a cleaner way.